# How do i write a regex for verifying a string that contains exactly 4 alpha 7 numeric characters respectively

Tags: string-matching

I have used everything I can find but nothing is working - the result is always false when i know it should be true. example of string format that needs to be verified: TGHU4674045

```
/A-Z{4}\d{7}/ 

/[(A-Z{4}0-9{7})]/

^(?=(?:\\d*\\D\\d*){4}$)[A-Za-z0-9]{7}$

/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{7}$/

^(A-Z{4})[A-Za-z0-9]{11}$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$
```

or

```
^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7}$
```